# button text wont go next to each other

Tags: html, css

I have made a button with the text "trail lesson" on it. but the text wont go next to each other for some reason

```css
/*.button {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 9vh;
  width: 5%;
  background-color: rgb(255, 196, 0);
  border: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 1rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 130%;
  left: 2%;
}
*/
.button {
  background-color: rgb(255, 196, 0);
  border: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 1.1rem 10rem;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
  height: 12vw;
  position: relative;
  margin: center;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<p class="center"><button class="button">trail lesson</button></p>
```

[image]

Comment: You need to increase the `width` of the button to keep the words on the same line.

Comment: i changed the width multiple times but it still wont fit

Comment: With the second of your two button styles it worked. See snippet above

Comment: Well, now the question is invalid

Comment: in the snippet it show correctly yes but in my code its shows under neath each other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick for you. The main problem was your padding. You can still use padding if you plan on using flexible width and height. You wont be needing the "center" class with this.

```
.button {
   background-color: rgb(255, 196, 0);
   border: none;
   color: black;
   text-align: center;
   text-decoration: none;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   font-size: 2rem;
   width: 20rem;
   height: 12vw;
   position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are taking padding 10rem from left and right so text will be side by side. make it 0 rem